# Get the default type of DbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, dbcontext

I'm trying to create logs on entries which undergone Add, Edit, Delete.
I also need to know their base type, and I come up with the following solution:

```
foreach (DbEntityEntry e in _context.ChangeTracker.Entries())
{
    if (e.State == EntityState.Added)
    {
        _log.Write(_context.Database.Connection.Database, "ADD", typeof(<Type>).Name, null, (<Type>)e.Entity);
    }
    else if (e.State == EntityState.Modified)
    {
        _log.Write(_context.Database.Connection.Database, "EDIT", typeof(<Type>).Name, null, (<Type>)e.Entity);
    }
    else if (e.State == EntityState.Deleted)
    {
        _log.Write(_context.Database.Connection.Database, "DELETE", typeof(<Type>).Name, null, (<Type>)e.Entity);
    }
}

_context.SaveChanges();
_log.Commit();
```

is there a way to get the "Entries" type, because it is stored as "object".
thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
Type entityType = ObjectContext.GetObjectType(e.Entity.GetType()).Name;
```